# bitwise OR and AND in c++

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I have

```
#define MS 0x0100|0x011
```

I need to check 0x011 present in MS. I use `MS & 0x011` which is giving value present. But id `MS & 0x10` also giving true value, I need it as false

Comment: `#define MS (0x0100|0x011)`

Comment: How about `(MS & 0x11 != 0x10) && (MS & 0x11 != 0x01)`?

Comment: If you AND with multiple bits, you check if *any* of the bits are set. Not if all bits are set.

Comment: I need true value only if 0x011 is present, for that i will be checking in loop from 1 to 10, but for other values also it will give true, any other way to implement this

Comment: *"I need to check 0x011 present in MS"* Sounds like you need a function `contains(MS, 0x011)`, why are you posting a `#define` macro?

Answer (score 1):

- `(value & mask) != 0` : is *at least one* of the set `mask` bits also set in `value`?
  (This is what `value & mask` is in a boolean context.)
- `(value & mask) == mask` : are *all* the set `mask` bits also set in `value`?

That is, the first is like "or" and the second like "and".

Answer (score 0):

(Edited)
You need

```
((MS) & 0x11) == 0x11
```

Thanks to lorro for his comment

Comment: I'm not sure it'll work: it'll result in `|` in `MS` being evaluated later than `&` in your code.

Comment: You're probably right. MS should be changed to (MS). I'll edit the reply, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `0x0100 | 0x011` will result in `0x111` which will result in all `&` tests for `0x1, 0x10, 0x100, 0x11, 0x110 and 0x111` to evaluate `true`.

You need to test your values directly, and will not be able to use your `#define`.

Comment: yeah.. this is the issue facing , the values to check is not exactly 0x11, it may vary in loop, need to get true only when checking against 0X11